# Is there any way to view Netbeans development output in a tabulated form or a seperate application?

Tags: java, debugging, jakarta-ee, logging, netbeans-7

I am building a Java EE application using NetBeans 7.1.1. I would prefer to view the output from the Glassfish server and Ant building process in a separate application. I've set up OtrosLogViewer to tail the glassfish server.log file as well as the applications log4j logs.  But I haven't figured out how to tail the ant build log. Nonetheless, while these work I'm hoping for a more elegant solution. (FYI: `tail` is a linux command that watches a specified log file and updates the output when changed, somewhat like the event viewer in windows)

What I like about OrtosLogViewer is that it uses a pattern to place the information into a tabulated table. That simply makes it easier for me to view what's going on behind the scenes without getting overwhelmed with stack traces. For instance, it's easy for 70% of the log to be taken up with the stack trace. Essential IF I need it but otherwise it's in the way.

Some alternative solutions:

1. A way to modify the logging output for netbeans in a tabulated table.(A plug-in maybe)
2. A way to send all the output from netbeans into a specified log file(s), which I can then tail with the application of my choice.
3. Any other ideas that makes it easier to view application debugging information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Ant calls a variable number of other tools while executing your build script, you are never going to find a perfect pattern for the format of it's output - the best you can do is match output like

```
[javac] Compiling X files...
[echo]  compilation done
```

with a format like `[tool] message`.

In other words, each component called in the Ant build script is likely to have different ideas of how to format the output.